# Linking two shared libraries together - undefined reference to symbol

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, symbols

I've got two shared libraries libA and libB, and I want to create a new library libC, that links to both libraries, so I can link my application with -lC instead of -lA and -lB. 
I can't use -lA and -lB one, because I'd have to fix many packages otherwise.

libB is a precompiled binary.

I tried to run this:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libA.so A.c
gcc -shared -Wl,--no-as-needed -L. -lA -lB -o libC.so
```

But when I link my application, that needs libB with -lC I

```
App.o: undefined reference to symbol 'SymbolInB'
```

`note: 'SymbolInB' is defined in DSO libB.so` so try adding it to the linker command line

```
libB.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
```

If I run `readelf -a libB.so` I see the SymbolInB in .dynsym, it is missing in libC.so. So I assume I miss a linking option to resolve the symbols correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. The functions in `libC` can use the functions in `libA` and `libB` fine, because `libC` was linked with the other libraries. However, those symbols from `libA` and `libB` are not exported from `libC`, so if you have an application which directly uses functions from `libB` then you need to link with `libB`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I'm thinking about writing wrapper functions (in `libC`) for every function from  `libB`. Could that approach work?

Comment: @user3860311 Yes it will work, but it's more work than just linking with the other libraries, and will introduce more sources for errors or problems. For example, think about what will happen if a function in `libB` changes, but you forget to change your wrapper?

Comment: Yes, that's why i want to avoid such a wrapper. What I try to achieve is: `libB` is a proprietary EGL library, which is missing some functions. `libA` implements these functions. `libC` consists of both libraries and is renamed to `libB`, so any application can use `libB` + the missing functions. Is there any other way to achieve this?